# Regex to extract text from inside an HTML tag

Tags: html, regex

I know this has been asked at least a thousand times but I can't find a proper regex that will match a name in this string here:

```
<td><div id="topbarUserName">Donald</div></td>
```

I want to get the name 'Donald' and the regex that's the closest is >[a-zA-Z0-9]+ but the result is >Donald.

I'm coding in PureBasic (It's syntax is similar to that of Basic) and it uses the PCRE library for regular expressions.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Josh's pattern will work if you only make use of the numbered group, not the whole match. If you have to use the whole match, use something like `(?<=>)(\w+?)(?=<)`

Either way, regex is widely known to not be good for parsing HTML.

Explanation:
`(?<=)` is used to check if something appears before the current item.
`\w+?` will match any "word"-character, one or more times, but stop whenever the rest of the pattern matches something, for this situation the `?` could have been left out.
`(?=)` is used to check if something appears after the current item.

Comment: Wow that regex actually worked thanks Can you explain it me what it does?

Comment: @user1420635 Added explanation of the pattern

Comment: How do you know that it wont extract the other parts of the string even though it's included in the regex .

Comment: @user1420635 I am not sure if I understand your question, but `(?=)` and `(?<=)` does not include their findings in the result. Basically the pattern means "match one or more word-characters if there is a > before it and a < after it."

Comment: Oh right - yes i was talking about (?=) and (?<=) thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

It should capture anything that is a letter / number

`>([\w]+)<`

Also I'm not exactly sure what your project limitations are, but it would be much easier to do something like this

`$('#topbarUserName').text();`

in jQuery instead of using a regex.

Comment: Make sure to the angled brackets are outside of the regex capture, the parenthesis.

Comment: Try removing the backslashes in front of the brackets. \> to >

Answer (score 1):

`>([a-zA-Z]+)` should do the Trick. Remember to get the grouping right.

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing it with plain old basic string-functions?

```
a.w = FindString(HTMLstring.s, "topbarUserName") + 16 ; 2 for "> and topbar...
If a > 0
b.w = FindString(HTMLstring, "<", a)
If b > 0
c.w = b - a
Donald.s = Mid(HTMLstring,a, c)
EndIf
EndIf
Debug Donald
```