# How can I find text on more than one line between XML tags

Tags: xml, regex, perl, xml-parsing

I have xml data like this

```
<DBCONNECTION>
 <SERVER>1111111</SERVER>
 <DBNAME>222222222</DBNAME>
 <USER>333333333333</USER>
 <PASSWORD>444444444</PASSWORD>
 <TABLENAME>5555555555</TABLENAME>
</DBCONNECTION>
<DBCONNECTION>
 <SE>ABC</SERVER>
 <DBNAME>DEF</DBNAME>
 <USER>GHI</USER>
 <PASSWORD>JKL</PASSWORD>
 <TABLENAME>MNO</TABLENAME>
</DBCONNECTION>
```

I wrote perl extract text between tag

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
@files = <*.xml>;
open my $out, '>', 'output.xml' or die $!;
foreach $file (@files) {
  open   (FILE, "$file");
  while($line= <FILE> ){
    if ($line =~ /<DBCONNECTION>(.*?)<\/DBCONNECTION>/)
    {
      $a=$1;
      print $out("$a\n"); 
    }
  }
  close FILE; 
}
```

But this works when there's no newline between the XML tags. Now i want find tag and extract if XML file contains newlines.

Comment: What do you mean by "enter mark"?

Comment: Entet mark mean enter character in keyboad its new line each xml tag.

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract the value of multi-line XML elements? Then you wouldn't parse the file line by line. I'm sorry, my comprehension of English is failing me.

Comment: Find all tag between <DBCONNECTION>(.*?)<\/DBCONNECTION> and write into text output file but my script work only xml contains without new line each tag.

Comment: Use a real XML library.

Comment: Can you tell me what is wrong in my script and why i cant do if xml tag comes in line by line.

Comment: Your script reads the file line by line, `while($line= <FILE> )`. Of course it's not going to find multiple lines between the XML tag. I've edited your question to make it intelligible, and I've also updated my answer. As Kevin said, use a real XML library.

Answer (score 2):

[Never use regular expressions to parse HTML (or XML for that matter).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Use a specialized library like [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig).

If you insist (others - *don't do this*), you can read the entire file in memory, then run the regular expression. It will fail in all sorts of cases, but you've been warned a few times already.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;  # also, learn to use strict
undef $/;  # no line separator; slurp files entirely in memory

my @files = <*.xml>;
open my $out, '>', 'output.xml' or die $!;
foreach my $filename (@files) {
  open my $file, '<', $filename or die $!;
  my $contents = <$file>;

  while ($contents =~ /<DBCONNECTION>(.*?)<\/DBCONNECTION>/sg) {  # note the /sg
    print $1, "\n";
  }
  close $file;
}
```

To learn what /sg does at the end of the regular expression, read http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers

Comment: Not for parsing xml extract text only.

Comment: Yes, for extracting text, [it's a bad idea to use regexps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11109969/1269037).

Comment: Can you give some example for when it will fail?

Comment: For example, when you have [CDATA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2784294/1269037) elements that contain `<DBCONNECTION>`, when there's whitespace in the tags, when tags with the same name are nested (`<DB>...stuff1<DB>more stuff2</DB> end of stuff 1</DB>`) etc. Trust us, use a real library.